# Unit test unityContainer.Resolve

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, unity-container, moq

In a class I am using this code:

```
    public User CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
            var httpContextHelper = unityContainer.Resolve<HttpContextHelper>();
            return httpContextHelper.GetUser();
        }
    }
```

This is in the `Bootstrapper.cs` file:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IHttpContextHelper, HttpContextHelper>();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(unityContainer));
    }
}
```

I cannot use constructor injection here because it is a base class and it would take quite some work to refactor.

But how would I unit test this? I cannot find a suitable method to mock `unityContainer.Resolve`.

Comment: This would throw an exception, you are creating a new container a then trying to resolve an interface on it while the interface has never been registered before. Is this intentional?

Comment: I think you should be using DependencyResolver.

Comment: @WiktorZychla this works ok, the registration has been done somewhere else. Code works, but how can I test this without proper DI?

Comment: How can the registration be done somewhere else? You're instantiating `UnityContainer`, then resolving on the very next line of code.

Comment: @Rogier21: until we learn the true structure of your code, we cannot help much. You say the registration is done somewhere else which means that the code you try to unittest does not look like the code you presented - you possibly simplified it.

Comment: I added the `bootstrapper.cs` resolver. But this won't be loaded with the unit tests I presume, so I am hoping there is some unity / moq magic that can inject into the resolver.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First things first the following code is wrong:

```
get
{
    var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
    var httpContextHelper = unityContainer.Resolve<HttpContextHelper>();
    return httpContextHelper.GetUser();
}
```

You are creating a new Unity container which of course is **empty** and then you are attempting to resolve some instances from this container which would simply call the default constructor of the `HttpContextHelper` class. Gosh I hate Unity for not throwing an exception when you attempt to resolve an instance of something that has never been registered into the container (which is what you are doing here). Instead it is silently calling its constructor with most known (registered) dependencies.

So this will not return the instance you have registered in your Bootstrapper because there you have a different instance of the UnityContainer in which you have registered the `IHttpContextHelper` instance.

So the first step towards refactoring this is to use the DependencyResolver:

```
public User CurrentUser
{
    get
    {
        var httpContextHelper = DependencyResolver
            .Current
            .GetService<IHttpContextHelper>();
        return httpContextHelper.GetUser();
    }
}
```

Now in your unit test you could write a custom dependency resolver:

```
public class DepepndecyResolverMock : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, object> kernel;
    public DepepndecyResolverMock(IDictionary<Type, object> kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.kernel[serviceType];
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

which you could configure for your tests:

```
var kernel = new Dictionary<Type, object>
{
    { typeof(IHttpContextHelper), new HttpContextHelperMock() }
};
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new DepepndecyResolverMock(kernel));
```

This being said, this code is still **horribly wrong**. It might allow you to unit test it but please I insist, this is wrong design. Do not use it. This uses the service locator pattern which is an **anti-pattern**.

The proper way to do this is to invert the control of this class so that it doesn't need to fetch its dependencies, but its dependencies need to be injected into it. So instead of wasting your time in useless patterns, refactor your code so that it uses real dependency injection.

Comment: I would not even mention the locator just to show it and say that it is an antipattern. Instead, you should probably expand the last sentence of your answer with a code example. Now, you have a nice example of wrong code and just a word on how it should be done correctly.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, the OP explicitly said that he cannot currently refactor his code to use proper dependency injection. I quote for you in case you haven't read the question: `I cannot use constructor injection here because it is a base class and it would take quite some work to refactor.` That's why I provided him with an example of how to solve the problem he was having with unit testing this code. As far as the correct way is concerned, that's pretty simple and obvious. This `CurrentUser` property simply gets injected into the containing class constructor because this class needs it.

Comment: I know how a proper code should look like and promoting a good style is always valuable. I somehow missed the fragment of problems with constructor injection, though.

Comment: Thanks both for the constructive criticism, I appreciate it. But are there any recommendations for this problem? I have this base class which is inherited by plenty MVC4 controllers. Problem is that this is not the only class that has to be resolved.